# Java Serialization for Dummies

Tags: java, serialization, io, deserialization, backwards-compatibility

I'm still working on the project I already needed a bit of help with:
[JavaFX - TableView doesn't update items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42557096/javafx-tableview-doesnt-update-items)

Now I want to understand how this whole Serialization process in Java works, because unfortunately, I don't really get it now.

Before I go on, first of all, I'm a *student*, I'm *not a professional*. Second, I'm neither familiar with using DBs, nor XML or JSON, so I'd just like to find solution to my approach, no matter how inelegant it might be in the end, it just needs to work. So please don't feel offended if I just reject any advice in using other techniques.

So here's what I want:
Saving three different class objects to separate files BUT maintaining backward compatibility to each of it. The objects are Settings, Statistics and a "database" object, containing all words in a list added to it. In the future I may add more statistics or settings, means adding new variables, mostly type of `IntegerProperty` or `DoubleProperty`.

Now the question is: is it possible to load old version saved files and then during the process just initiate new variables not found in the old version with just `null` but keep the rest as it has been saved?

All I know is that the first thing to do so is not to alter the `serialVersionUID`.

---

Another thing would be saving the whole Model object (which contains the three objects mentioned before), so I just have to implement stuff for one class instead of three. But how would that work then concerning backward compatibility? I mean the class itself would not change but it's attributes in their own class structure.

---

Finally, what approach should I go for? And most of all, how do I do this and maintaning backward compatibilty at the same time? I do best with some concrete examples rather than plain theory.

Here are two **example** methods, if it's of any help. I already have methods for each class to write and read an object.

```
public static void saveModel(Model model, String destination) throws IOException
{
    try 
    {
        fileOutput = new FileOutputStream(destination);
        objectOutput = new ObjectOutputStream(fileOutput);
        objectOutput.writeObject(model);
    }
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally
    {
      if (objectOutput != null) 
      try 
      { 
           objectOutput.close(); 
      } 
      catch (IOException e) {}

      if (fileOutput != null) 
      try 
      { 
          fileOutput.close(); 
      } 
      catch (IOException e) {}
    }
}

public static Settings readSettings(String destination) throws IOException, FileNotFoundException
{
    Settings s = null;

    try 
    {
        fileInput = new FileInputStream(destination);
        objectInput = new ObjectInputStream(fileInput);

        Object obj = objectInput.readObject();

        if (obj instanceof Settings) 
        {
            s = (Settings)obj;  
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (ClassNotFoundException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally 
    {
        if (objectInput != null) try { objectInput.close(); } catch (IOException e) {}
        if (fileInput != null) try { fileInput.close(); } catch (IOException e) {}
    }

    return s;
}
```

Tell me if you need more of my current code.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You close the stream *before* writing to it? That will blow up in your face.

Comment: Then: You *write* `Model` and you *read* `Settings`? How's that supposed to work? Apart form that: For saving Settings, there are [Property](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) files or maybe you could alternatively use XML. I wouldn't use binary serialization for that. Bins are not human readable. XML or Propertyfiles will allow you to see the settings in cleartext in a simple text editor. Backward compatibility is also easier to do.

Comment: These were just two example methods, one to write, the other to read, I already have methods for each class.
And the settings aren't really supposed to be readable and since I still have to serialize the other data, I can do it with the settings the same way.
Also, I have no experiences with XML.

Comment: In that case, I'd suggest using a DB for all. Binary serialization will lead you into a dead end, here I guess.

Comment: why you don't use json or xml or db for this rather than serialization ?

Comment: Ain't familiar with that either, I'm just a student and I never did these things before. How about this tho: is there like any possibilty to catch the version of a file and according to that creating an object of that version and then manually convert it to the new version? Means keeping the old class and maybe it's not that elegant but I just want this to work, it's nothing I will publish somewhere so I don't really care if it's perfect, it just needs to work.

Comment: OR just checking `instanceof` either fileV1 or fileV2 n then create a new object accordingly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### ... you must be this tall

Best advice for Serialisation is to avoid it for application persistence, especially if backwards compatibility is desired property in your application.

#### Answers

> Is it possible to load old version saved files and then during the process just initiate new variables not found in the old version with just null but keep the rest as it has been saved?

**Yes**. Deserialising objects saved using previous versions of the class into a new version of this class will work only if:

- fully qualified name of the class has not changed (same name and package)
- previous and current class have exactly the same `serialVersionUID`; if one of the versions is missing it, it will be calculated as a 'hash' of all fields **and methods** and upon a mismatch deserialisation will fail.
- inheritance hierarchy has not changed for that class (the same ancestors)
- no fields have been removed in the new version of the class
- no fields have become `static`
- no fields have become `transient`

> I just have to implement stuff for one class instead of three. But how would that work then concerning backward compatibility?

**Yes**. Providing that all classes of all fields of `Model` and `Model` class itself adhere to the rules above.

> Finally, what approach should I go for? And most of all, how do I do this and maintaning backward compatibilty at the same time?

**Yes**, as long as you can guarantee all of the above rules **forever**, you will be backwards compatible.

I am sure you can appreciate that forever, or even for next year can be very hard to guarantee, especially in software.

This is why people do application persistence using more robust data exchange formats, than binary representation of serialised Java objects.

Raw data for the table, could be saved using anything from **CSV** file to JSON docs stored as files or as documents in NoSQL database.

For settings / config have a look at Java's `Properties` class which could store and load properties to and from `*.properties` or `*.xml` files or separately have a look at **YAML**.

Finally for backwards compatibility, have a look at [FlatBuffers](https://google.github.io/flatbuffers/index.html#flatbuffers_overview)

The field of application persistence is very rich and ripe, so happy exploring.